# Deploying golang app in cmd folder to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a pre-existing golang project with the a following folder structure (minimized the folder for readability).

```
- postgre
    - service.go
- cmd
    - vano
        - main.go
    - vanoctl
        - main.go
vano.go
```

Now since my project web server is in `./cmd/vano` I need to create a custom `Buildfile` and `Procfile`. So I did that

Here is my Buildfile

```
make: ./build.sh
```

build.sh file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Install dependencies.
go get ./...
# Build app
go build ./cmd/vano -o bin/application
```

and finally my Procfile:

```
web: bin/application
```

So now my folder structure looks like this:

```
- postgre
    - service.go
- cmd
    - vano
        - main.go
    - vanoctl
        - main.go
vano.go
Buildfile
build.sh
Procfile
```

I zip up the source using git:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD > vano.zip
```

And upload it to AWS Beanstalk. How ever I keep getting errors and AWS errors don't seem to be the most read. Here is my error

```
Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
```

Error Message

```
[Instance: i-0d8f642474e3b2c68] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...' Failed to execute 'HOME=/tmp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/foreman start --procfile /tmp/d20170213-1941-1baz0rh/eb-buildtask-0 --root /var/app/staging --env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/elasticbeanstalk.env'. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/01_configure_application.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Extra Error info:

```
Failed to execute 'HOME=/tmp /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/ruby /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby/bin/foreman start --procfile /tmp/d20170213-1941-1baz0rh/eb-buildtask-0 --root /var/app/staging --env /var/elasticbeanstalk/staging/elasticbeanstalk.env'
```

Comment: It may have failed to install a dependency. What does it say in `/var/log/eb-activity.log` file?

Comment: Why don't you vendor the dependencies and then zip the code. No need to do `go get ./...`.

Comment: It looks like foreman failing, is your Procfile valid?

Comment: @KennyGrant My Procfile is taken pretty much from the AWS documentation

Comment: @MayankPatel I could easily do that except I would have to vendor from the `cmd` folder which to me that just seems wrong

Comment: To debug this solution you'd probably have to provide more info, why don't you put up a minimal problematic setup on github or similar and people can try it out. I'd rule out the procfile first by setting up a simple project with a procfile that works, then substitute in your one. Hard to debug without more info though.

Comment: mass's comment was what helped with this error - for me, looking in the logs revealed that build.sh didn't have permission to execute (chmod +x) so I changed my buildfile to `make: sh build.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach here instead of using a procfile etc would be to cross-compile your binary (usually pretty painless in go) and upload it that way, as per the simple instructions in the guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html

You can just compile it locally with:

```
GOARCH=amd64 GOOS=linux go build -o bin/application ./cmd/vano
```

Then upload zip of the application file and it should work, assuming your setup only requires this one binary to run.

Comment: This is the approach I've had to take not the way I wanted it to be plus I don't like the fact that it adds a bin folder to my application but it seems to be the easiest solution

Comment: I use this solution personally and am quite happy with it, you can use the latest Go 1.8 (AWS is on Go 1.6 isn't it?), it speeds up deploys, and you can see and fix any errors locally before upload, and it makes you less dependent on AWS infrastructure as it can be used anywhere (GC, VPS etc). I don't mind the bin folder :)

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead to check this answer it doesn't fully "answer" the question but its does provide a working solution.

Comment: This is great! This will allow me to use Go 1.8! but how about the folder structure, assets and such, do I keep them all the same? Just add the bin/application? Can I write to disk in a relative folder (ie. ./data) with this approach?

Comment: Bit late to the party here, but you can include the above line in build.sh, meaning you don't need to include the binary in your source file

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deploy is creating a binary file using cmd.

In the terminal create a binary file using cmd->  `go build -o bin/application application.go`

then add all the files in a **zip** file.

go to your eb environment and upload the zip file.

You should see logs as below:

[image]